# PHP Regex preg match

Tags: php, html, regex

sorry to ask a question here.

I have a source code below, how do I preg match the http://www5.videouploadsite.com:182/d/skxxkycgz3b4quuoh6ueyzatiu7edyaim5x57picrg67ydu4eupttmie/video.mp4

The pattern i am finding is video.mp4 in this case is to find string that is contain within a single quote ' ' and the ending is video.mp4

what kind of regex pattern should I deploy to preg match the result.

**Thanks for helping**

```
<div id="player_code"></div>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
                    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Mobile/i)){
                jwplayer("player_code").setup({
                    file: 'http://www5.videouploadsite.com:182/d/skxxkycgz3b4quuoh6ueyzatiu7edyaim5x57picrg67ydu4eupttmie/video.mp4',       
                    image: 'http://www5.videouploadsite.com/i/00051/663d3hthe6ym.jpg',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    provider: 'http',
                    startparam: 'start',                    
                    abouttext: 'videouploadsite',
                    aboutlink: 'http://www.videouploadsite.com/',
                sharing: {
                code: '<IFRAME SRC="http://www.videouploadsite.com/embed-663d3hthe6ym.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=650 HEIGHT=370></IFRAME>',
                link: 'http://www.videouploadsite.com/663d3hthe6ym'
                }
                }); 
                    } else {
                     jwplayer("player_code").setup({
                    file: 'http://www5.videouploadsite.com:182/d/skxxkycgz3b4quuoh6ueyzatiu7edyaim5x57picrg67ydu4eupttmie/video.mp4',       
                    image: 'http://www5.videouploadsite.com/i/00051/663d3hthe6ym.jpg',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    provider: 'http',
                    startparam: 'start',
                    primary: 'flash',
                    skin: 'http://www.videouploadsite.com/player/J6/bekle.xml',
                    abouttext: 'videouploadsite',
                    aboutlink: 'http://www.videouploadsite.com/',
                sharing: {
                code: '<IFRAME SRC="http://www.videouploadsite.com/embed-663d3hthe6ym.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=650 HEIGHT=370></IFRAME>',
                link: 'http://www.videouploadsite.com/663d3hthe6ym'
                }
                });
                }
                </script><script>
                jwplayer().addButton(
                "http://www.videouploadsite.com/player/J6/download.png",
                "Download Video", 
                    function() {
                        window.open("http://www.videouploadsite.com/663d3hthe6ym"); 
                        return false;
                    },
                    "download"
                );
            </script>


<!-- Video ADs code start here -->
```

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML/JS source as a string? Is this from an external source that you have no control over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/file:\\s'(.*)'/uix", $searchText)
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/bL4pF7

Comment: How do I get match[0] and match[1] after the command above, can I assign result to variable $matches

Comment: yes, exactly - `preg_match("/file:\\s'(.*)'/uix", $searchText, $matches); `

Answer (score 0):

This will search for a single quote, followed by anything, followed by the characters video.mp4, followed by a single quote

```
preg_match("/'.*video\.mp4'/", $text_to_search_from)
```